# Grunt Task - freeing up the port

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, libsass

I setup this.

http://www.zell-weekeat.com/grunt-sass-with-susy/

It works fine for one run then, if I exit out of the sass watch I can't free up the port.

```
Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process.
```

Then

```
sudo lsof -i :35729
```

gives

```
\COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
grunt   26305 author   12u  IPv6 7064373      0t0  TCP *:35729 (LISTEN)
```

How do I get this port to free up

Comment: How did you start it? how did you ran it?

Comment: And did it went to a background shell or is it a front run? did you stop it?

Comment: was a front run and used control+z to suspend  it.

Comment: Sounds like you just answered the question. if your proccess is suspended in the bg the socket is still open and the port is caught. Kill the procces, and next time shut it with ctrl+c

Comment: it was a front run and stopped it with control+z should have been control+c

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just for organization sake, as mentioned in comments:

You should stop a process with `Ctrl+C` in the terminal.

`Ctrl+Z` will keep it running.

If you need to kill it, find the PID with `sudo lsof -i :35729` and then `kill -9 PID`.

Comment: evaluate@evaluate-Lenovo-G50-80:/var/www/html/ecommerce$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process.


Execution Time (2016-09-01 14:59:55 UTC+5:30)
loading tasks                214ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 44%
loading grunt-contrib-watch   70ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 14%
Total 485ms

It worked for me...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep -i : <port>`. kill it with `kill -9 PID`